# probability function for event whose probability increases over time.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, python

I'm trying to figure out what kind of probability function would be appropriate for the following problem (my goal is to program this in Python, for what its worth).

Consider a snake, and the number of molts it has in one year as a juvenile. On average, it molts bi-monthly.  The probabilty of molting right after a molt ~0%, and increases slowly up to the bi-monthly point, where I'd expect the mean to be, and some to molt within a month after that.

I envision something like the probit model, but not sure if thats something I can draw random numbers from?

I am looking to throw this into a simulation, so something I can draw some sort of random number from to determine a "YesMolt", "NoMolt" each day for the snake.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you can use a survival analysis model. Hope it helps https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis